# Using NetGraph as FeatureExtractor?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'd like to compute FeatureDistance between two images with a NetGraph:

```
rs = NetModel["ResNet-152 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"];
fe = NetTake[rs, {1, -3}]
```

Ok, so this works:

```
FeatureNearest[imgs -> {"Index", "Distance"}, FeatureExtractor -> fe]
```

But then why doesn't this:

```
FeatureDistance[img1, img2, fe]
```

[image]

Is there a way to turn a `NetGraph[]` into a valid `FeatureExtractorFunction[]`?

Comment: Sorry why use Features stuff ? you are just computing `Norm@Differences@fe@{img1,img2 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

```
net = NetChain[
   {ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}], AggregationLayer[Mean]},
   "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {64, 64}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}]
   ] // NetInitialize
```

[image]

```
imgs = Table[RandomImage[1, {64, 64}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"], {20}];

fe = FeatureExtraction[imgs, net]
```

[image]

```
FeatureDistance[imgs[[1]], imgs[[2]], fe]
```

> 0.0268319

Comment: Ok great. However there's something weird going on in FeatureDistance: `fe = FeatureExtraction[imgs, NetTake[rs, {1, -3}]]
FeatureDistance[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 
 ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}], fe]` the distances are only 0 or 1... unless I set DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance. Do you know what  FeatureDistance does by default?

Comment: @user5601 `EuclideanDistance`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky1wD.png